# What is the word for suddenly remembering something you used to say or do consistently, then because of that memory you begin to do whatever that was?

Tags: phrase-requests

It’s not a memory. The closest that I can think of would be restore, revive or rekindle but none of them feel correct. It’s not a very formal word, I feel like I’ve used it in my daily life without ever taking note of it if that makes any sense?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

to "pick up an old habit" maybe?

Comment: Can you improve your answer by giving some reference?